# what is the proper syntax for a Typescript IIFE?

Tags: typescript

I have this function Javascript that works.  But when converting to Typescript, I am now getting a red squiggly in my editor:

[ts] Cannot find name 'ordersAppAPI'.
any

```
export default window.timersAppAPI = (function () {
  function getTimers(success) {
    return fetch('/timersapp/api/timers', {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    }).then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .then(success);
  }


  function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json();
  }

  return {
    getTimers
  };
}());
```

Whats the proper syntax?   Thank you

Comment: You just export what you'll need. In this case `export function getTimers...`

Comment: I don't see `ordersAppAPI` in that code. But it's unclear why you think you need a IIFE in TS.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript works with modules, so you can either

```
export default function timersAppAPI
```

without IIFE and bundle it with a tool like webpack or set it with

```
window.timersAppAPI = function() { ..here goes your code }
```

IIFE is a pattern to provide like module system in browser without any bundlers